# Excel 2013: Adding Workdays to date and time

Tags: excel-2013

All,

I am trying to calculate the end date AND time to an SLA based off of a cell reference containing date AND time.

Currently, the portion of the nested IF function looks like this: G5="P3", WORKDAY(H5,1,0)
Where G5 is a cell reference for priority, and H5 is a cell reference to a start date AND time.

My issue arises because I need to add a full 24 hours to the start date, but the WORKDAY function seems to not account for time of day, resulting in the correct day but the time of 12:00 AM. I didn't use TIME because I need to ignore weekends and holidays (when applicable) which is included in WORKDAY.

If anyone can help work the two functions together, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
DD

Answer (score 0):

You have an odd way of 'reporting' your formula but I think what you want may be:

```
=IF(G5="P3",WORKDAY(H5,1,0)+MOD(H5,1))
```

This simply adds the time component from H5 to the result without. The time component is the decimal part of the value in H5, which can be extracted with [=MOD](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mod.php).